# How can I automate a task on a certain event?

Tags: ubuntu, scheduling

Playonlinux and WINE are great. Finally I can have my favourite games and the joys of Linux without having dual-boot or filling my disk with Windows crap! But some are quite old, and only run on lower resolutions. Fortunately, I keep a terminal emulator open, and just do `xrandr -s 1366x768`. Sometimes it's hard though: on `800x600` I can't scroll down, nor see what I'm writing. And I know exactly the processes that change the resolution. That got me thinking: can I automate it?

I know with `crontab` I can shedule tasks for certain hours, or on startup. But what about scheduling for when some specific script runs, or ends? Or even for when the system gets stuck, to kill the guilty process? How can I schedule tasks for any event? Do I need another program?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: There's no completely generic event mechanism. You need to either hook on something that detects the event (such as cron for times, inotify for file changes, dbus for various GUI- and DE-related events, etc.) or do your own monitoring.

Comment: @Gilles, what about "signal traps" slm referred?

Comment: There are only a very small number of [signals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_signal). GUI events, file changes, etc. don't cause a signal to be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the script in a shell script and run the shell script instead.

```
#!/bin/bash

### xrandr command to set display size downsized
xrandr -s 800x600

... run program ...

### xrandr command to reset display back to normal size
xrandr -s 1366x768
```

Comment: Good idea. But isn't there another way for an action to be executed whenever a certain event happens. Independently? Checking the processes or something... Just curious.

Comment: What would the event be? What are you thinking is an "event"? There are events but using a signal trap here is way more complicated than what I showed you.

Comment: A signal trap? I'm curious, that seems what I'm looking for; how does it work? Can you add it (maybe as a proof of concept)?

Comment: @JMCF125 - in Unix there are signals, you familiar with these? For example when you `kill` a process you're sending it either a 9 or 15 signal to exit.

Comment: @JMCF125 - you can see examples of the `trap` command here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-usingtraps/. I'm not going to write it up since I know from experience they're the wrong solution here. What I laid out is the way to do this. The examples in that tutorial are good at showing you how to use traps though.

Comment: great! Thanks for the link and having a better idea than "signal traps" as an answer.

Comment: @JMCF125 - one other things I should mention, when a command runs it typically returns a status code. In Bash you can see these after a command runs by doing this: `echo $?`. A 0 usually means success. So you could interrogate this after "..run program.." to make sure that it exited cleanly before resetting the display w/ `xrandr`. But I can't think of a reason when you wouldn't just want to reset it, so it's redundant, but thought you'd like to know about it, non the less.

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple scripts together while executing them.

e.g.: If you want to make the system shutdown after your system finishes updating, you can run both of them together using a `;` in between. Like
`sudo apt-get update; sudo poweroff`

Similarly, in your case, while invoking the wine program, you can run them via the terminal or write a shell script to do the same which executes something like:

`xrandr -s 800x600; path/to/program -parameters; xrandr -s 1366x768`

As soon as your program ends (and doesn't return any errors as its exit code), the terminal should run the final code of your script above. You don't need the first part of the above code if your program automatically changes the resolution to 800x600.

Edit: As pointed out by @slm, use `;` instead of `&&` since if one of the command returns false, the rest of the commands will not get executed. Corrected my answer accordingly.

Comment: Be careful when using this construct. If program returns false this will die here and not run the 2nd `xrandr`. See here for why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Control_Operators_.28.26.26_and_.7C.7C.29 and here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Grouping_Statements

Comment: @slm, yes, and my game does crash often. `;` should be used instead, right?

Comment: @JMCF125 yes, don't do it this way! That's why I showed you my way for something like this. Worst case is it will skip the program line and reset the screen.

Comment: @slm, still, I don't think this should have been downvoted. It does help a bit. I'll upvote it (and your answer too, I forgot).

Comment: @slm: thanks for pointing that out, you're right :)

Comment: @JMCF125: I've edited my answer accordingly in case someone uses it for future reference. Thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: @JMCF125 - though helpful it's dangerous b/c it shows something that on the surface might work but won't for the reasons I said. It's generally a bad practice to use this pattern in this manner here. I've taken off my DV, but this is just my answer now.